# Makefile: why makefile with % does not work?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

% in my makefile didn't work.

I've tested the makefile on ubuntu 16.04 x64.

My makefile code is that:
Version 1

```
CC=gcc
OBJ=main.o
TARGET:=main
.PHONY: clean
all : main
# ${OBJ}:%.o:%.c

%.i : %.c
        $(info Preprocess: build main.i)
        ${CC} -E -o $@ $<

%.s : %.i
        $(info Compile: build main.s)
        ${CC} -S -o $@ $<

%.o : %.s
        $(info Assemble: build main.o)
        ${CC} -c -o $@ $<

main : main.o
        $(info Link: build main.o)
        ${CC} -o $@ $^

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.out *.s *.i *.asm *.map ${OBJ} main
```

run make, the terminal print message:

```
gcc    -c -o main.o main.c
Link: build main.o
gcc -o main main.o
```

So only the last rule(main: main.o) run .
fist step is autoderived code (gcc    -c -o main.o main.c).
why other rules didn't run？

And then I modify 3rd rules, add static mode:
Version 2

```
...
%.i : %.c
        $(info Preprocess: build main.i)
        ${CC} -E -o $@ $<

%.s : %.i
        $(info Compile: build main.s)
        ${CC} -S -o $@ $<

main.o : %.o : %.s
        $(info Assemble: build main.o)
        ${CC} -c -o $@ $<

%: %.o
        $(info Link: build main.o)
        ${CC} -o $@ $^
```

Then all rules take effect, display message :

```
Preprocess: build main.i
gcc -E -o main.i main.c
Compile: build main.s
gcc -S -o main.s main.i
Assemble: build main.o
gcc -c -o main.o main.s
Link: build main.o
gcc -o main main.o
rm main.i
```

(why run "rm main.i"?)

I modify makefile again:
Version 3

```
%.o:%.c
        $(info build main.o)
        ${CC} -c -o $@ $<
main : main.o
        $(info Link: build main.o)
        ${CC} -o $@ $^
```

It can be run correctly. Print message:

```
build main.o
gcc -c -o main.o main.c
Link: build main.o
gcc -o main main.o
```

So, why version 1 can't work correctly？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because `make` knows how to build an object file (`.o`) from a `.c` source, is a [built-in implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)

You can disable implicit rules, if you run your version 1 with `make -r` it should run as expected.

The `.i` file is removed because is an intermediate file, by default `make` remove all intermediate files, you can avoid that by using `.PRECIOUS: some-file-name`

`%` rules in makefiles are referred as *stem*, *pattern rules* (not *wildcards* which are another thing)

You can run `make` with the argument `--debug` or `--debug=all` for a verbose log or a more verbose log

**edit**

You have two more options to disable built-in rules and get version 1 working:

- override a specific built-in rule with an empty rule, just add `%.o: %.c`
- disable all built-in rules adding an empty suffixes list `.SUFFIXES:`

> If you modify the suffix list, the only predefined suffix rules in effect will be those named by one or two of the suffixes that are on the list you specify

**edit**

An additional option to disable built-in rules that I used in the past:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules
```

Comment: Good answer.  OP should note also that pattern rules are specific to GNU `make`.  Of course that's fine if they are not concerned about compatibility with other implementations, but one should always maintain awareness of when one is relying on extensions to a standard tool.

Comment: Thank you， so priority of implicit rules is higher than pattern rules（without  explicit object）, I think static mode with explicit object should be needed for avoiding implicit rules take effect. So i rewrite makefile with static mode.

Comment: @Edward I don't know if is a priority, but surely `make` think is an option, if you had a `.s` file existing maybe the rule `%.o:%.s` would be used (I didn't check)

Answer (score 1):

Static mode with explicit object should be needed for avoiding implicit rules take effect. So i rewrite makefile with static mode. It can work correctly and don't run "rm main.i".

```
CC:=gcc
SRCS:=          $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ:=           $(patsubst %.c, %.o, ${SRCS})
PREFILE:=       $(patsubst %.o, %.i, ${OBJ})
ASMFILE:=       $(patsubst %.o, %.s, ${OBJ})
TARGET:=main
all: ${TARGET}
.PHONY: clean distclean

$(PREFILE):%.i:%.c
        $(info Preprocess: build main.i)
        $(CC) -E -o $@ $<

$(ASMFILE):%.s:%.i
        $(info Compile: build main.s)
        $(CC) -S -o $@ $<

$(OBJ):%.o:%.s
        $(info Assemble: build main.o)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
        @objdump -DrwC -Mintel $@ > $(patsubst %.o,%.o.asm,$@)

$(TARGET):$(OBJ)
        $(info Link: build main)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ -Wl,-Map=gcc.map
        @objdump -D $@ > $(patsubst %,%.asm,$@)

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.out *.s *.i *.asm *.map ${OBJ} ${TARGET}

distclean : clean
        rm -f *.d
```

Comment: Looks good, I used stem patterns a lot in an old project and I don't recall having this option but maybe I just miss it at the time, if you need retro compatibility you may want to check since when this feature is available